# What do I watch after finishing the original Naruto series?

Tags: naruto

I just finished the last episode of *Naruto* on Netflix. It was the episode where Naruto went out on a journey with Jiraiya. What episode should I watch next? Do I go straight into Shippuden?

Answer (score 3):

Well, like you said, you just finished Naruto. There isn't something in between Naruto and Naruto Shippuden so, it's time you get into Shippuden.

Additionally, I recommend watching Naruto by skipping fillers, except for the ones where they show the past.